# How to Append rows to an Excel Sheet?

Tags: delphi, excel, delphi-2007

I am developing an application that need to generate excel sheets. How do we append rows
to an existing excel sheet? I am using Delphi 2007.(and I am using SM Software TXLS... components...but I am ok with answers in native delphi excel components).
Thanking you all,
Pradeep

Answer (score 5):

Over the years, I've found Deborah Pate's site has helped me by providing useful code samples: http://www.djpate.freeserve.co.uk/AutoExcl.htm. We use the CreateOleObject approach.

Comment: +1 for the link to Deborah Pate's site. Very useful info there on Office apps in general.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you won't need to append rows, because you can just reference any cell to write in it. You may need to *insert* rows in the middle of your sheet like this:

```
ExcelApplication.ActiveSheet.Rows[10].Insert;
```

or

```
ExcelApplication.ActiveSheet.ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert;
```

If you develop for Excel, I think it is more convenient to use TExcelApplication because it is just a wrapper around the type library. You can use the source code of the imported type library as a reference. Another helpful tool is the macro recording in Excel itself. The VBA code created by recording a macro can easily be translated into Delphi code. Sometimes you need to do little changes or improvements, but it is still a lot of help when you are stuck.

Comment: @GolezTroi: I disagree about using ExcelApplication as a general rule. It requires Excel to be installed on the machine running your application (not always possible, for instance when writing an app that runs on a server), and is often considerably slower than alternate solutions. XLSReadWriteII, for example, is lightning fast writing or reading spreadsheets, and doesn't require Excel at all. I use it in lots of utility apps that process data and export to Excel, including some that run on a server that doesn't know MS Office even exists. (Of course, it produces Excel XP and earlier formats.)

Comment: @Ken, you're right. I answered this because OP told us that he was ok with using these components. I figured that the mentioned TXLS made use of Excel as well, and in that case, using the type library directly would be easier. But I see now that TXLS doesn't use Excel and writes the files itself. That is indeed a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hier some untested sample code you can use to insert data to Excel:

```
var
  Cols: integer;
  Rows: integer;      
  Excel, XLSheet: Variant;
  failure: Integer;

begin
  failure:=0;
  try
    Excel:=CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  except
    failure:=1;
  end;
  if failure = 0 then
  begin
    Excel.Visible:=False;
    Excel.WorkBooks.Open(<Excell_Filename>);
    XLSheet := Excel.Worksheets[1];
    Cols := XLSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
    Rows := XLSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;

    //Insert Data
    Excel.Cells[1, 1].Value := 'SwissDelphiCenter.ch';
    Excel.Cells[2, 1].Value := 'http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch';
    Excel.Cells[3, 1].Value := FormatDateTime('dd-mmm-yyyy', Now);

    Excel.Range['A2', 'D2'].Value := VarArrayOf([1, 10, 100, 1000]);

    // Save the Workbook
    Excel.SaveAs(Excell_Filename);

    Excel.Workbooks.Close;
    Excel.Quit;
    Excel:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;
```