# Insert a Row into Excel

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, excel-2010

I'm trying to persuade Excel to Insert a row from a Delphi application.

Normally I would just append the new data to the end of the spreadsheet but the brief for this  application has a tight Template design to follow.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114484/how-to-append-rows-to-an-excel-sheet) has an answer where GolezTrol suggests the following code:

```
ExcelApplication.ActiveSheet.Rows[10].Insert;
```

or

```
ExcelApplication.ActiveSheet.ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert;
```

Using Excel2010 I get either an "Undeclared Identifier 'Rows'" or "Undeclared Identifier: ActiveCell" when I try and compile either option.

Any suggestions that allow me to do it this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using early binding, the answer you mention in the question you linked is for late binding. You can test that answer with code like:

```
var
  Excel: OleVariant;
begin
  Excel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  Excel.Visible := True;
  Excel.Workbooks.Add;
  Excel.ActiveSheet.Rows[10].Insert;
  ...
```

However the object model is somewhat different with early binding interfaces. You can find the reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms262200%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

An example of inserting a row can be like the following. Suppose 'Workbook' refers to a valid workbook, you can then insert a row at the 10th row like this:

```
var
  Range: ExcelRange;
begin
  Range := (Workbook.ActiveSheet as _Worksheet).Range['A10', 'A10'].EntireRow;
  Range.Insert(xlShiftDown, Null);
  ..
```